# regex: match line and proceeding lines until match but include contents before and after match

Tags: regex

I am trying to scan a log file until *match1* shows up then proceed to match all lines after *match1* until the *match2* is found.  But! I need to also match the contents before *match1* on the same line and the contents after *match2* also only on that same line.

So far I am using the following with mutliline flag but I cannot figure out how to gather the before and after content on the respected lines of the matches.

`match1(.*)match2`

Text:

```
2015-05-05 17:08:25 name: this line should not be included  
2015-05-05 17:08:25 name: match1  
2015-05-05 17:08:25 name: contents and stuff  
2015-05-05 17:08:25 name: match2 more stuff  
2015-05-05 17:08:25 name: this line should not be included
```

I want to match:

```
2015-05-05 17:08:25 name: match1  
2015-05-05 17:08:25 name: contents and stuff  
2015-05-05 17:08:25 name: match2 more stuff
```

**Note:** the beginning of each line will not always be numbers and sometimes there will be complete blank lines between the intended match.

Comment: Which regexp dialect? grep? awk? Ruby? PCRE?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the multiline option (`/m` or `(?m)` in most flavors) and *not* using the singleline option (`/s` or `(?s)`), you can match this with

```
.*match1[\s\S]*?match2.*
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/oB8wR7/2).

**Explanation:**

```
.*        # Match any number of characters except newlines
match1    # Match "match1"
[\s\S]*?  # Match any number of characters including newlines, as few as possible
match2    # Match "match2"
.*        # Match the rest of the characters on that line
```

Comment: Don't even need the anchor, the greed will take care of it.

Comment: that's it! perfect thank you so much.  Also ty for sharing the regex101 link.  I've been using several other live testing sites but this one is the best by far with the explanations.